# Convert matrix from R to Python (numpy)

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I'm new to R and trying to convert some code to Python, but struggle with this line:

`mat <- matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2)`

more specifically it is this part:

`matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2)`, where I think it tries to join two vectors into a 2 column vector?

So far I have this:

`mat = np.matrix(tuple(x,y))`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first argument is the content of the matrix, the second argument is the shape (there could also be a `nrow=1`, but that's left implicit)

```
matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

would create

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

see e.g. [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/matrix/).

so this should be equivalent to:

```py
np.matrix([[x, y]])
```